MSP430 ADC with internal vref not working with USI and UART
I have an MSP430G2231 and I'm trying to get an ADC reading from port 1.5. I'm expecting a range of 2.0 to 3.3V, which I'm dividing to a range of 0.8 - 1.3V with a voltage divider. The divider is fairly large (1M7Ω / 1M7Ω) to accomodate for current leaks when not in use. I'm using port 1.0 as the source for the divider, and only enable it when doing a reading. I've measured and confirmed the output range of the divider to be around the expected range of 0.8 to 1.3V. My ports and timers are set up as such:
  BCSCTL1 = CALBC1_1MHZ;                            // Base clock to 1MHz
  BCSCTL1 |= DIVA_3;                                // ACLK/2
  BCSCTL3 |= LFXT1S_2;                              // ACLK = VLO

  WDTCTL = WDT_ADLY_1000;                           // Interval timer
  DCOCTL = 0;                                       // Select lowest DCOx and MODx settings
  DCOCTL = CALDCO_1MHZ;

  IE1 |= WDTIE;                                     // Enable WDT interrupt

  P1OUT = 0xC1 ;                                    // All P1.x reset, P1.6 & P1.7 & P1.0 to out
  P1REN |= 0xC0;                                    // P1.6 & P1.7 Pullups
  P1SEL = UART_TXD;                                 // Timer function for TXD pin (P1.1)
  P1DIR = 0xFF;                                     // Set all pins to output on port 1
  P2OUT = 0x00;                                     // All P2.x reset
  P2SEL = 0x00;                                     // Don't configure anything (for now)
  P2DIR = 0xFF;                                     // Set all pins to output on port 2
  P1OUT &= ~BIT0;                                   // Disable P1.0
  AdcInit();                                        // Initialize ADC
  AdcDisable();                                     // Immediately disable ADC since it's not needed right now

For the ADC I've based the functions on this tutorial, with the addition of an ADC disable call for disabling the ADC when not in use. My modified functions for the ADC look like this:
void AdcInit(void)
{
    ADC10AE0 = BIT5;                                // Set sampling pin
    ADC10CTL0 = SREF_1 + ADC10SHT_3 + REFON + ADC10ON;        // Enable ADC-core, 64 cycles sample time.
    ADC10CTL1 = INCH_5 + ADC10SSEL_2 + CONSEQ_0;    // Initialize ADC channel, clock source MCLK (At 1MHz), single sample
}

void AdcStart(void)
{
    ADC10CTL0 |= ADC10ON;                           // Turn on ADC
    __delay_cycles(1000);                           // Give time for ADC to stabilize
    ADC10CTL0 |= ENC + ADC10SC;                     // Start ADC conversion
}

void AdcDisable(void)
{
    ADC10CTL0 &= ~ENC;                              // Stop conversion
    ADC10CTL0 &= ~(ADC10ON + REFON);                // Turn off ADC core and reference to save power
}

int GetAdcValue(void)
{
    while( ! (ADC10CTL0 & ADC10IFG));               // Wait for conversion ready flag
    ADC10CTL0 &= ~ADC10IFG;                         // Clear ready flag
    AdcDisable();                                   // Disable ADC core
    return ADC10MEM;                                // Return ADC reading
}

As seen during Initialization, I'm calling the Initialize function with disable directly afterwards to make sure the ADC isn't started prematurely.
In my loop I have around 1.5 seconds of time between calling AdcStart(); and GetAdcValue();, In which after the MCU enters LPM3 for a set amount of time.
For some reason with this setup, I always get a pin reading of 1023 or 0x03FF every time GetAdcValue(); is called, even when the input never goes over 1.3V, which should be well within the range of the internal 1.5V vref.
The reason I'm disabling the internal Vref after every read and taking drastic measures with the divider to prevent current leakage, is because I'm using this for an ultra low-power application, in which the MCU reaches nanoampere current consumption in sleep mode.
Note that messing with the clock setup makes both USI and UART behave inconsistently, which I need for I2C and Serial.
Could it be that the large 1M7 resistors cause somekind of issue with the ADC? Or is there a limitation with the internl Vref when the microcontroller's VCC goes under 3V? I'm not so sure about the low input voltage for the MCU being an issue for the 1.5V Vref, since I'm still getting a reading of 1023 at both 3.0V and 3.3V.
In short:
With my current clock setup and code, the ADC only reads it's maximum value (1023) over P1.5, even when it's input voltage is within the range of the internal Vref of 1.5V.
Please let me know if additional details are needed.

What debugging have you done so far? Have you temporarily disabled all the power down calls? Have you tried tying the sampled pin to ground to see if the ADC returns 0? Do you have an oscilloscope or at least a multimeter that can confirm the sampled voltage? What other steps have you taken?

@pion The issue seems to be within the AdcInit() and AdcStart(). I removed the AdcDisable()-call from my initialization, and then the ADC makes a proper reading once, until I try to call AdcStart() again after calling AdcDisable(). There's something that AdcDisable() "disables" that the AdcStart() can't recover from properly. However I still need to disable at lest the internal reference before going back to LPM3, since it draws far too much current when it's not in use. And yes, I've confirmed the divider output to be within range with a multimeter as I mentioned in my inital post.

Ok so if you completely remove all instances of AdcDisable() and all other power-saving functions, does your code continuously work correctly?

I can't test my hypothesis as I'm away from my MSP430 boards, but please investigate the following.
Quoting from the code in the question:
Hypothesis: After enabling REFON in AdcInit():

void AdcInit(void)
{
    ADC10AE0 = BIT5;                                // Set sampling pin
    ADC10CTL0 = SREF_1 + ADC10SHT_3 + REFON + ADC10ON;        // Enable ADC-core, 64 cycles sample time.
    ADC10CTL1 = INCH_5 + ADC10SSEL_2 + CONSEQ_0;    // Initialize ADC channel, clock source MCLK (At 1MHz), single sample
}


later code disables the built-in reference by clearing REFON in AdcDisable() here:

void AdcDisable(void)
{
    ADC10CTL0 &= ~ENC;                              // Stop conversion
    ADC10CTL0 &= ~(ADC10ON + REFON);                // Turn off ADC core and reference to save power
}


and no code enables REFON again.
Since you set SREF_1 in ADC10CTL0 and SREF_1 means the ADC upper reference is the output of the reference generator, then the reference generator must be enabled for doing ADC conversions, in that configuration.
How to test: Either try not disabling REFON in AdcDisable() or reenable it in AdcStart().

This answer is effectively explaining the "something" you mentioned in your comment where you said:

There's something that AdcDisable() "disables" that the AdcStart() can't recover from properly.

Yep. That's REFON.

I'm concerned about the possible inaccuracy of ADC readings when using that high-impedance voltage divider at the ADC input, but that won't cause readings to peg at 1023 as you're reporting. If anything, it will cause readings to be lower than they should be. Let's see if you can get working readings from the ADC first, as you are asking. Then if you have problems with accuracy, that can be a new question.

(For anyone who is interested, the ADC module in the MSP430G2 is described in the TI MSP430G2 Family User's Guide (currently Rev.K) here.)

Should I omit REFON from the initialization sequence, and then add it to AdcStart();?

Ok, I've removed ´REFON + ADC10ON´ from the second line of AdcInit(); and moved them to the first line of AdcStart(); ´ADC10CTL0 |= REFON + ADC10ON;´ Now the device initializes without the ADC and VRef, but AdcDisable(); no longer turns it off. the power consumption jumps over 100uA after AdcStart is first called, and doesn't go back down after calling AdcDisable();

Disregard my previous comment. I tried saving memory by adding ENC from the first line of AdcDisable() to the second line, making the function a single liner in order to save memory(which it did), but it ended up no longer working. I changed it back to a 2-liner at the cost of a souple bytes and it works now. I'm open to suggestions on how I could optimize these memory-wise, I'm getting fairly short on program memory.

As for the ADC accuracy, the readings at a stable 3.3V fluxuate between 958 and 960, which is a lot but plenty accurate for my uses.
